# iOS CoreBluetooth security

Tags: ios, swift, security, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm working on an iOS app that uses Core Bluetooth to communicate with a BLE device. The ble device, which I'm working with might be secured, because it looks, that I have to send some code, before communication (now it's sending no data, even after enabled notification). It's possible that some device has this kind of security? If yes, how I can send the data, to 'unlock' it ?